# Attribute in Spring data MongoDB aggregate is always null

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have the following code to try to group by the modelId and show two different counts:

```
 DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$group", new BasicDBObject(
            "_id", "$response.modelId")
            .append("okCount", new BasicDBObject(
                            "$sum", new BasicDBObject(
                            "$cond", new Object[]{new BasicDBObject("$and", new Object[]{new BasicDBObject("$ne", new Object[]{"$responseData", null}), new BasicDBObject("$eq", new Object[]{"$responseStatus", null})}), 1, 0})
                    )
            ).append("notOkCount", new BasicDBObject(
                            "$sum", new BasicDBObject(
                            "$cond", new Object[]{new BasicDBObject("$ne", new Object[]{"$responseStatus", null}), 1, 0})
                    )
            ));
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("response.modelId").ne(null)), new CustomGroupOperation(query));
    AggregationResults<RequestTraceCount> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "RequestHistory", RequestTraceCount.class);
```

I do get the right counts but because the modelId is nested inside response, I get _id equal to null in every result.

How can I fix this?

This is what the result looks like:

```
 [{"okCount": 301,"notOkCount": 66,"_id": null},{"okCount": 11,"notOkCount": 6,"_id": null}]
```

This is a sample document from the collection:

```
{
"_id" : "01e71704-0f40-4c34-8685-dee990b6f38c",
"response" : {
    "id" : "6b728429-2f28-4588-b045-15198a8c50ac",
    "modelId" : "c902cdbc-b4e2-4ca2-a2eb-beb827705325",
    "modelCode" : "EDBW",
    "validFrom" : 201507,
    "validTo" : 201909
},
"responseData" : { /* large object */
    },
"responseStatus" : null
}
```

Here are the classes RequestTraceCount and CustomGroup Operation

```
public class RequestTraceCount {
@JsonProperty("_id")
private UUID modelId;
private int okCount;
private int notOkCount;

public UUID getModelId() {
    return modelId;
}

public void setModelId(UUID modelId) {
    this.modelId = modelId;
}

public int getOkCount() {
    return okCount;
}

public void setOkCount(int okCount) {
    this.okCount = okCount;
}

public int getNotOkCount() {
    return notOkCount;
}

public void setNotOkCount(int notOkCount) {
    this.notOkCount = notOkCount;
}
}






class CustomGroupOperation implements AggregationOperation {
private DBObject operation;

public CustomGroupOperation(DBObject operation) {
    this.operation = operation;
}

@Override
public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
    return context.getMappedObject(operation);
}
}
```

Comment: I have to add that I can not use the ConditionalOperators class cause my Spring Data version does not support it.

Comment: I don't see any issues with the query. May be mapping is not working.  How is your `RequestTraceCount` and `CustomGroupOperation` defined ? Can you add that to post as well ?

Comment: Renaming modelId in RequestTraceCount to _id fixed it. What a stupid mistake. I thought the annotation would make it read the JSON attribute correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the spring mongo annotation `@Field("_id")` to map it back correctly.

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

@Field("_id")
private UUID modelId;
```